# Подключение дебаггера к первой инструкции

Tags: java, intellij-idea, отладка

Как подключить дебаггер Intellij Idea к первой инструкции (к первой команде кода 
в методе `main`)? Обычно вначале запускается программа, потом к ней подключается дебаггер, и, т.к. запуск программы происходит всегда очень быстро, брейкпоинты не останавливаются на первых операциях (только на операциях, которые выполняются спустя какое-то время после запуска программы, спустя пару секунд). Есть ли возможность одновременного запуска программы и подключения дебаггера, чтобы дебаггер мог остановиться на первой инструкции? Может быть, есть какие-нибудь параметры запуска JVM или другие средства для осуществления этого?

Comment: Я честно не знаю всех тонкостей запуска отладчика в idea, но у меня ни разу отладчик не пропускал брейкпоинты. Поэтому не совсем понятна ваша проблема

Comment: Речь о запуске в программы в IDEA или подключении отладчиком к уже запущенной программе?

Comment: @Nofate, при подключении отладчиком к удалённому приложению, не в IDEA

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы запускаете JVM с включенным отладочным портом, вы в командной строке передаете что-то вроде такого:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

Если присвоить параметру `suspend` значение `y`, то JVM будет ожидать подключения отладчика перед тем как запустить ваше приложение.